# Date function not working on Label in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

I've a dropdown named "testDateField" and a label named "testLabel".

In the dropdown, I've data as month/year. For example:
01/2019
02/2019
03/2019
04/2019
05/2019
06/2019
07/2019
08/2019
...
...

Now, in the testLabel; I want to use the below formula:

`Date(Right(testdatefield.SelectedText.Value, 4), Left(testdatefield.SelectedText.Value, 2), 1)`

With this formula, I can get the first day of the month which is selected from the dropdown.

Ideally, I should get 08/01/2019 on selecting 08/2019 from the dropdown.
Example-2: On selecting 01/2019 from the dropdown, I should get 01/01/2019 in the label.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [functions Left and Right](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-left-mid-right) return a text value; to use them in the [Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-date-time) function you need to convert them to a number, which you can do with the [Value function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-value):

```
Date(
    Value(Right(Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value, 4)),
    Value(Left(Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value, 2)),
    1)
```